# Combining relative time expressions in NLP in python?

Tags: python, datetime, nlp, nltk, stanford-nlp

I am working on extracting dates from natural language texts, and am wondering what might be the most efficient way of doing the following:

I have journal entries with dates as titles extracted as named entities with StanfordCoreNLP wrapper for python such as "2018-07-13", and from in text dates such as "last monday", which refers to the monday before the title date. I would like to be able to standardize "last monday" to "2018-07-09" in my data.

I looked into SUtime, but it appears there is no way to set the relative title date as reference to the in text date in python, or at least I cannot figure out how to do it with the wrapper. What would be the best course of action?

Comment: Well.... it looks like what you're writing is not true. I took a look at [SUTime documentation](https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/sutime.html) and it's point to [SUTime online demo](http://nlp.stanford.edu:8080/sutime/process) which allows to set reference date.

Comment: Hello! Thank you for answering, I edited the question to be more clear. I have not figured out a way to do this reference date setting with python.

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/FraBle/python-sutime) is python library for wrapping Stanford CoreNLP's SUTime. In [this file](https://github.com/FraBle/python-sutime/blob/master/sutime/sutime.py) you can find `def parse(self, input_str, reference_date=''):` method which takes `reference_date` parameter. Just use your titles as value of this parameter and it should work.

Comment: Thank you, I have tried installing this library, but have had no success in getting it to work.

Comment: It might be easier to help if you paste your code and tell what library do you use for wrapping SUTime.

Comment: The library you linked, I have followed the installation instructions have all jar files and java dependencies work fine on other wrappers. I'm just trying to run the example code on the github page, and keep getting an error that not all java dependencies have been loaded...